# Add Member Button Disabled

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an issue. I am in the Google Developer Dashboard for Google Cloud and the Add Member button is disabled. I am the owner. Creating a new project and going to Permissions does show the button enabled.

[image: GC]

Comment: maybe its something that can only be done after you "enable billing"? just a guess

Comment: @pulkitsinghal Nope, I have projects that are not billing-enabled, but I can feel free to click on the 'Add member' button.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening to you, but I would suggest you to go to Google Issue Tracker at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list to file an issue to ask assistance on this. Since no one here would have access to look into what is really going on with your project and account.